# Weblogic administration console way too slow

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, jvm, weblogic

I've installed weblogic 10.3.3, configured simple domain with default configuration. And after starting weblogic I cannot use it via admin console because it is starting too slow (~10 mins). It seems that admin console application is being deployed incorrectly. Even when I enable 'staging' mode in AdminConsole deployment options, it does not help. Does anybody have a solution for this problem? It really bugs me out.

---

Configuration properties:

**Server:** [Dell PowerEdge r410 server](http://www.dell.com/us/en/highered/Servers/server-poweredge-r410/pd.aspx?refid=server-poweredge-r410&cs=RC956904&s=hied#reviews) (Six-core Intel®  Xeon® x64 CPU, 8GB RAM)

**OS:** Ubuntu Maverick 10.10 x86_64

**Weblogic:** 10.3.3 x64 (used wls1033_generic.jar file for installation)

**Java:** 1.6.0_17_i586 (tried with different jdk's including x64, but it does not work either)

Comment: Have you enabled deployment of the console app at start-up time itself? or does it deploy on first request?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Turns out weblogic uses random number generator during startup. Because of the bug in java it reads random bits from `/dev/random`. There are almost no problems with `/dev/random` except that it is extremely slow. It takes sometimes 10 minutes or more to generate one number. Simple solution exists – using `/dev/urandom` instead. It is not that good as `/dev/random`, but at least it is instant.
Java somehow maps `/dev/urandom` file to `/dev/random`. That’s why default settings in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` are useless, they just do not make any sense.

Problem fix is very simple – adding string `export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"` to the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. Usage of `/dev/./urandom` instead of simple `/dev/urandom` is another hack. JVM does not understand the option value otherwise.

Be aware of this problem if you try to setup weblogic under UNIX-based OS.

Comment: [Bug 4705093: Use /dev/urandom rather than /dev/random if it exists](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093) and [Bug 6202721: SHA1PRNG reads from /dev/random even if /dev/urandom selected](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6202721) explain some of the background of this. A shame that it's still a problem after such a long time.

Comment: @BurhanAli: I can say that it this bug cost me a job :( real shame

Comment: Oh dear. Sorry to hear that. :(

Comment: Just another of Java "non-issues" (and I like Java otherwise). There are even bugs to preserve backward compatibility, which is ... abominable. Let's save some trouble to people using Java for 5 years and cause even more trouble for the rest of them that will be using it for next 30 or so. Sometimes I even wish Java dies sooner for sins like this. :-( Real shame. Especially when you hit this bug with Oracle product (wls 11g 10.3.6). Obviously this question/answer saved me tons of troubles. Big thanks

Comment: what to do in case windows machine ?

Comment: Better to clarify that this works for Debian-based Linux flavors (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/815066/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-and-etc-bash-bashrc). For other distributions add it to the WebLogic process owner in ~/.bashrc (not sure for /etc/profile though).

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the startup logs we could only speculate.  Weblogic typically is a beast.  It typically takes anywhere fromo 6-8 minutes to start up for me on my development machines, but that seems like a nice server for it to take 10 minutes for you.

Comment: On a reasonably configured machine, WebLogic Server will run up fairly quickly - a vanilla WebLogic Server domain will come up in under a minute. If the domain has more complex applications deployed (particularly frameworks like SOA Suite or WLI) then it can take longer, but that's the application initialising, not WebLogic Server itself. The distinction between WebLogic Server's boot time and your applications initialising is an important one.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin Console should not be this slow, nor should it take 6-8 minute to start a server or deploy the Admin Console.  The deployment of the admin console on my machine takes less than 30 seconds, and startup is under 60 seconds.  Startup time for WebLogic is a common complaint, but chances are that something is misconfigured if there is a very long startup or admin console deployment time.

Comment: have you changed any default configuration ?