# PL/SQL package call via JDBC performance issue

Tags: performance, oracle, jdbc, plsql, prepared-statement

I have to use an PL/SQL package as API for importing data into an Oracle database. I'm doing this within an Java application with the latest ojdbc driver. All statements (of cause PreparedStatements) I'm using during the import are initialized only one time and reused for every set to import.

Now I'm  facing following problem: The first call of an procedure of the package takes over 90% of the time for one set. I have to call about 10 procedures during the import and the first one takes about 4 seconds the rest about 0.4 seconds. It doesn't matter if it's the 10th or 100,000th set to import the first procedure call allways takes that time.

Important to know is, if I'm calling another procedure on first position this on takes the 90%. So, may be I'm wrong, it is something about the package initialization? But if I'm (re-)using prepared statements, shouldn't that happen only at first call?

The PL/SQL package has about 10,000 lines of code and also calls several other packages during the import.

So now my questions are:

What are possible reasons for this problem? And what are potential solutions?
Are there any tools I can use to identify the causer?

**EDIT:** I could identify the cause of the slow import. It had nothing to do with wrong code or something. The reason was simply the kind of data I used in my test scenario. My mistake was importing allways the same data.

If thread one made an update on a data-set in the first procedure it was holding an lock on this row until the commit after the complete import. Thread two to n were trying to update exactly the same row. The result is effectivly a synchronization of all threads.

Comment: The package body has a Begin - End section?

Comment: Yes it has begin and end section.

Comment: how about concurrency? Are multiple processes using the same procedure at the same time?

Comment: Do you see the same sort of delays if the procedures are called from, for example, SQL*Plus rather than Java?  In other words, is the slowdown caused by JDBC or is it just that the packages run slowly?

Comment: @ik_zelf yes, there are 8 parallel threads, is is not possible to access it from different threads?

Comment: you can call the proc from different processes concurrently, no problem with that. What happens in the proc? It could be locking rows/tables that cause you waiting.

Comment: @SKiontke and? what is in the begin - end section? That code is executed once, at first reference to the package(that is first procedure). At next procedure is not executed. Is this code sufficiently heavy to explain your delay at first procedure?

Comment: @FlorinGhita the code in the begin - end section is not very heavy. only some logging is done. if i call the same procedure from pl/sql developer it's fast.

Comment: @ik_zelf if i call another procedure first, this one is slow. if it's a lock problem, the execution time shouldn't change for the procedure, isn't it?

Comment: @BobJarvis I've used the profiler in pl/sql developer. The execution is very fast there.

Comment: How fast you obtain the connetion in java? Have you profiled the every step(before connection, after connection, before first proc, after first proc, etc)?

Comment: @FlorinGhita i'm using ucp for pooling. the connection is not closed or even returned to pool between the several imports. the step which takes long is only for the execute() of the (first) PreparedStatement.

Comment: setup a trace with wait events and see what appears in the raw trace file. With a little luck it gives a clue.

Comment: Might it be this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5706310/966703 We had problems with slow initial JDBC connections at work and it turned out to be caused by that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is not normal.  So there is definitely something awry with your code.  But without being able to see your source there's no way we're going to be able to spot the problem.  And frankly I don't want to debug 10000 LOC, not even mine let alone yours. Sorry.

So the best we can do is give you some pointers.

**One:**

> "The first call of an procedure of the package takes over 90% of the
>   time for one set. ....  if I'm calling another procedure on first
>   position this on takes the 90%"

Perhaps there is some common piece of coding which every procedure executes that behaves differently depending on whether the calling procedure is the first one to execute it in any given run.  You need to locate that rogue code.

**Two:**

> " I've used the profiler in pl/sql developer. The execution is very
>   fast there. "

Your program behaves differently depending on whether you call it from PL/SQL Developer of JDBC.  So there is a strong possiblity that the problem lies not in the PL/SQL code but in the JDBC code.  Acquiring database connections is definitely one potential source of pain.  Depnding on your architecture, network traffic may be another problem: are you returning lots of data to the Java program which is then used in subsequent procedural calls?

In short: you either need to identify something common in your PL/SQL code which can cause the same outcome in different proocedural calls or identify what happens differently when you call the program in PL/SQL Developer and JDBC.