# Docker WebLogic 11g container network issues after restart

Tags: docker, weblogic

I'm setting up Oracle WebLogic 11g (10.3.6) in a Docker container (1.11) following [Bruno's guide and docker files](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/01a9c51d66b16af32c0b3888e1ad5426180c4295/OracleWebLogic/samples/11g-domain). I'm using History to grab the files for WL 11g since it's not official supported.

I have built all required components and am able to startup containers and WebLogic just fine, however after restarting the container WebLogic slows down considerably.

The container starts with: `CMD ["startWebLogic.sh"]`. If I use the WL Admin Console to stop the server, or use `docker stop <container_name>`, then use `docker start <container_name>` the container will come up, but Admin Console requests take 5+ minutes to complete.

Everything works fine on a fresh container using something like `docker run -d --name wlsadmin --hostname wlsadmin -p 7001:7001 1036-domain` but as soon as the container is restarted everything grinds to a halt.

I am not making any changes to the defaults. Simply starting a new container, stopping the container, and starting it back up again.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue and get to the root cause?

I have also created WL 12.1 and WL 12.2 containers that all work successfully, even after restarts, but my legacy app only runs on WL 10.3.6, so I'm really trying to figure this out for 11g and am stumped.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is related to WebLogic and not Docker, namely how long it takes to generate random numbers.

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702512/weblogic-administration-console-way-too-slow)

While the docker files did attempt to compensate for this, the implementation was not successful. I was able to fix the docker files and the Admin Console's performance returned to normal.

Comment: This is fixed on trunk =)